# How to make your private ethereum block chain non mine-able?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, genesis

I have made a private instance of ethereum and I want to make it non-mineable once after it is deployed. How will I be able to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "non minable" ?

Comment: by non mine-able I mean, others should not be able to connect to my network and mine ether

Comment: Don't connect to internet. Don't open ports. Use firewall. ETC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use another consensus system than PoW. Many exist that do not need rewards to work. For instance PoA with IBFT. Start a network with predefined validators, an initial balance on some accounts and the network will not generate more ETH ever. No mining.

Try this tutorial using Hyperledger Besu https://besu.hyperledger.org/Tutorials/Private-Network/Create-IBFT-Network/

Disclaimer: I wrote a part of this doc page.
If you have any Besu specific question, ask on our Rocketchat community.

Comment: I will still be able to generate tokens by smart contracts, is this the case? Because, this is what want to achieve. A non mine-able block chain, but I generate tokens as per my need and distribute them among users of my blockchain.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you can create and interact with smart contract, you are free to do whatever you want, ERC20 or others. Note that you can also have a zero gas price network so you don't event have to pay for creating contracts and user do not need to pay fees to use them.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! This is exactly what I want to have, no gas fee.
Also, please do tell me what do I have to set the value of gas limit in the genesis file to make the the gas fee zero for every transaction, thanks

Comment: For Besu, look at the doc under zero gas price network. There's a genesis file example provided.